# Expand width to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I have a fixed width container.
In which i have a footer which is stuck in the fixed width wrapper. i want to expand the footer width 100%.

I cannot modify the html code. I need a guidance how can i make the footer 100% keeping it in fixed wrapper.

I tried to make it work through position relative / absolute.

This is my code.

```
<style>
    .wrapper{ width:980px; margin:0 auto}
    .body{background:red}
    .footer{ width:100%; background:green}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="body">Main body contain</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: What you have there should work just fine. Perhaps I'm not understanding the issue?

Comment: @RiteshK I have a limitations in html code i cant make any changes in html code. I want to expand the footer 100% (screen width). Right now footer is 100% but it is inside the fixed wrapper. So I am not able to expand the footer in full browser.

Comment: OP has clearly stated their goal you guys, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by absolute positioning `.footer`. Change what you have to the following.

```css
.footer {
    background:green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

If you add `position: relative;` to `.wrapper` this will not work and your footer will be contained within `.wrapper`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qkes6ba/

Answer (score 1):

position absolute will work for you

```
   .footer {
    position: absolute;
        background:green;    
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `width: 100vw;` which means 100 viewport width. and is not relative to container, like percentages.
You will still need to position it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.wrapper{ width:980px; margin:0 auto}
.body{background:red}
.footer{ position:absolute; left:0; width:100%; background:green}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/hpvvnpyf/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `wrapper` class is set to have a width of `980px` which causes the width of the `footer` class when set to 100% only be as big as `980px`.

```
<style>
  .wrapper{ width:980px; margin:0 auto}
  .body{background:red}
  .footer{ width:100%; background:green}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="body">Main body contain</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```